# Laravel e JWT - Não gera o token (invalid credentials)

Tags: php, autenticação, jwt, laravel-5.2

Estou com um problema usando o seguinte código:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'senha');
try {
   if(! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
     return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
   }
}catch(JWTException $e){
   return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
}

return response()->json([
  'access_token'  => $token,
  'token_type'    => 'bearer',
  'expires_in'    => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
]);
```

Quando utilizei em um usuário criado aos padrões do Laravel, a autenticação funcionou perfeitamente, mas... quando alterei para o meu banco de dados, eu já não consegui mais fazer a validação.

A senha do usuário esta encriptada com bcrypt, ao fazer um **Hash::check()**, o retorno é **true**, porém, a validação do JWT sempre esta me retornando falso.

Verifiquei alguns artigos como [esse](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/184#issue-95707468) da própria pégina do recurso e alguns outros só que não consegui encontrar a solução!

A versão do laravel é a 5.2!